# gridview not showing on page populating uisg jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am populating gridview using jquery ajax. Below is the code i have used.

$(document).ready(function () {

```
        $('#gvData').empty();
        load_data(0, 10);
    });

    function load_data(iPageIndex, iPageSize) {
        $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "GridAjaxDotnetSpan.aspx/BindEmployees",
            data: JSON.stringify({ iPageIndex: iPageIndex, iPageSize: iPageSize }),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {
                $('#gvData').empty();
                $('#gvData').append("<tr><th><input type='checkbox' id='chkOrgheader' name='chkOrgheader' onclick='selectAll();' /></th><th>EmpId </th><th>EmpName </th><th>empsal </th><th>empaddr </th></tr>")
                for (var i = 0; i < result.d.length; i++) {

                    $("#gvData").append("<tr><td><input type='checkbox' id='chkOrgRow' name='chkOrgRow' onclick='selectChildRec(this);' /></td><td>" + result.d[i].EmpId + "</td><td>" + result.d[i].EmpName + "</td><td>" + result.d[i].empsal + "</td><td>" + result.d[i].empaddr + "</td></tr>");
                }

            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });
    }
```

and Below is my gridview

```
            </asp:GridView>
```

I have above through debugging, all the rows are appending to grid(gvData) properly but grid is not displaying on to page.

Please help.

Comment: where is your _actual_ gridview code, can you please update it and show us

Comment: <asp:GridView ID="gvData" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true"
                                ForeColor="#333333" AutoGenerateColumns="true" PageSize="10">
                                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                                <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
                                
                            </asp:GridView>

Answer (score 0):

Try this code please. Hope this will work .. !! or let me know if you have added update panel.

```
       function load_data(iPageIndex, iPageSize) {
        try {
            $.ajax({

                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "GridAjaxDotnetSpan.aspx/BindEmployees",
                data: JSON.stringify({ iPageIndex: iPageIndex, iPageSize: iPageSize }),
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(result) {
                    //If you have your data as Json string than here parse your Json string.
                    result = JSON.parse(result.d);
                    var tempHtml = "";
                    if (result) {
                        var tempheader = "<tr><th><input type='checkbox' id='chkOrgheader' name='chkOrgheader' onclick='selectAll();' /></th><th>EmpId </th><th>EmpName </th><th>empsal </th><th>empaddr </th></tr>";
                        $("#<%=gvData.ClientId %>").find("thead").html(tempheader);
                        $("#<%=gvData.ClientId %>").find("tbody").empty();
                        for (var j = 0; j < result.length; j++) {
                            tempHtml += "<tr><td><input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"chkOrgRow_" + j + "\" name=\"chkOrgRow_" + j + "\" onclick=\"selectChildRec(this);\" />";
                            tempHtml += "</td><td>" + result[j].EmpId + "</td><td>" + result[j].EmpName + "</td><td>" + result[j].empsal + "</td>";
                            tempHtml += "<td>" + result[j].empaddr + "</td></tr>";
                        }
                        $("#<%=gvData.ClientId %>").find("tbody").html(tempHtml);
                    }
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert("Error");
                }
            });
        } catch (e) {
            alert(e.description);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I dont have update panel. I have placed my gridview in a table td. I checked with your code still it is not showing.

Comment: May be css issue you are facing .. !!